# Putting a suffering animal out of its misery - Mitzvah, Reshut or prohibition?

Tags: halacha, animals, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

How does the concept of Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim deal with putting an animal out of its misery by killing it in order to prevent unnecessary pain (of the animal)?

For instance, when one sees an animal with a broken spine lying on the side of the road and he cannot take it to the vet without hurting it, and one cannot, for whatever reason, bring a vet to the animal, or else assume that one *is* a vet and can determine that there is no way to nurse the animal back to health.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12087/128

Answer (score 4):

This answer  is from [Dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2011/09/13/cruelty-to-animals-halachos-of-tzaar-baalei-chayim/):

> Killing Animals to Prevent their Suffering
>
> The Chazon Ish is cited (in Dinim Ve-Hanhagos Mi-Maran Ha-Chazon Ish
>   Vol. 2, p. 40) as having been asked by a member of the family how a
>   dying fly should be treated. The Chazon Ish responded that the fly
>   should be killed, so as to prevent its extended suffering.
>
> However, it is possible (Tzaar Baalei Chayim Chap. 4, no. 3) that this
>   ruling will only apply to small insects, and not to larger animals,
>   such as mice, and so on. The reason for this is that with regard to
>   larger animals, killing the animal—even if done to prevent its
>   suffering—is perceived as an act of cruelty, and therefore it should
>   be avoided even for noble motives.

Comment: So... Maybe, maybe not, you’re not sure? At least this answers the question by insects, so +1 for that.

Comment: In another version of this ruling [here](http://dinonline.org/2015/12/20/killing-sick-or-injured-animal/) dinonline rules "Yes [euthanasy is the right course of action], as there is no available treatment [or at least anyone willing to provide it] [euthanasy] will end the animal’s suffering and remove danger from humans." - you might wish to add this

Answer (score 0):

I would like to discuss some aspects of צבע"ח. This topic is very loaded emotionally, and it is crucial to neutralize one's emotions while discussing it Halachicly.

1. There's no Halachic reference to animals other than being a property. As such, **one is free to make any use of it including making it suffer or killing it** (don't rush!) as long as one benefits from it. If one does not benefit from injuring or killing HIS animals he's probably transgressing בל תשחית, but nothing from יורה דעה. (*See JT Shabbat 7,2 explanation of עורות אילים מרודמים that the animals were beaten to make their skin red, or Soyto 9-10 about letting the blood of an animal before sacrifice*). This approach is called scientifically ["Anthropocentric Ecology" or Anthropocentrism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropocentrism).
   This is פשיטא from the explicit verses of the Torah:

> "ויברך אותם אלוקים ויאמר להם אלוקים פרו ורבו ומלאו את הארץ וכיבשוה ורדו בדגת הים ובעוף השמים ובכל חיה הרומשת על הארץ"
>
> "ומוראכם וחתכם יהיה על כל חית הארץ, ועל כל עוף השמים, בכל אשר תרמוש האדמה ובכל דגי הים, בידכם נתנו. כל רמש אשר הוא חי לכם יהיה לאוכלה כירק עשב נתתי לכם את הכל"

2. The same logic applies to Hafker animals, that one is free to catch or make use of or kill for any need incl. fun (*Nodah BeYehuda openly permitted hunting for fun only, but many opposed*). Therefore, killing an animal is defaultively allowed and by itself does not fall under צעב"ח at all.
3. The whole concept of צעב"ח is questionable as all the Mitzvot we learn it from have some weird limitations, e.g שילוח הקן is limited to עוף טהור, אותו ואת בנו is limited to defectless animals, פריקה וטעינה is limited to חברך etc.
4. Therefore צעב"ח was never unified in any form of Halacha, and it is only mentioned "by the way" when other Mitzvot are discussed (Se Rambam Avida, Rotzeah also in Shu"A)
5. Most Poskim agree that the concept is used not as a practical Mitzvah, but as a tool to exercise one's Midos in order to mimic Hashem's qualities ( חסדים ורחמים). Therefore, the Mitzvah will not be the חפצא - to help the animal, but גברא - to use the situation to exhibit and exercise good Midos. The story about Rebbi (BM 85a shows exactly that - he did not show his sympathy), or the opposite - to prevent developing bad Middos such as cruelty (See Rem"O אה"ע סי' ה' סעי' י"ד).
6. As the matter of Midos, two people might be acting completely differently and still "performing the Mitzvah of צעב"ח" - One might express his compassion by killing it immediately, another might only pet it, and still another by spending a fortune to find a cure.

---

*I'm sorry to stop, I can go on and on but hope this will suffice.*

Comment: Hm. Interesting approach. I’d be curious to see the Noda BiYehudah, as I’m almost certain that he’s a Da’as Yachid.

Comment: 1. Even you admit that one cannot kill an animal for the sake of killing an animal (i.e. assuming that one does not derive joy from it and does not derive any other benefit either). So I’m not sure how accurate “killing an animal is [by default] allowed” is. 2. I hear your point re: Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim being a Middah not a Mitzvah, but what do you think the Gemara means in BM 32 when it asks whether it’s D’Oraisa or D’Rabbanan? If it were just a good Middah to practice that’s a nonsensical question.

Comment: 1. I never said anything about liability. All I asked was if it’s permissible, not if one can be punished by Beis Din for it. 2. I don’t see anything in that discussion asking if there is an explicit mitzvah of Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim. The discussion starts with מדברי שניהם נלמד צער בעלי חיים דאורייתא - according to Rava, even R’ Shimon holds that צעב״ח is from the Torah. The maskana is that צעב״ח is d’Oraisa according to all opinions except R’ Yosi HaGelili (הא מני ריה״ג היא שאמר צעב״ח לאו דאו׳), a position repeated throughout 33a until the end of the sugya.

Comment: I found an [OU article](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/jewish-ethicist/judaism_and_hunting/) that refers to a Teshuvah by the Noda BiYehudah on the topic. Is this what you’re referring to? Because if so, you seem to be misrepresenting his opinion. He does say that it’s permissible, but he adds two caveats - that the animal be killed quickly, with no torture; and that you probably shouldn’t be doing it, even if it is technically okay. If this is the Teshuvah you’re referring to, you should edit it in.

Comment: I further found a [Chabad article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1589324/jewish/The-Jewish-View-on-Hunting-for-Sport.htm) that, in addition to the Noda BiYehudah quoted by the OU, also quotes other possible prohibitions, ranging from Bal Tashchis to Leitzanus (though you might call that latter one just a bad Middah rather than a bona fide lav).

Comment: 2. If it's D"O why Rambam does not bring it in his count? As I said - it is D"O but not a Mitzvah.

Comment: When reading a Teshuvah it is important to distinguish the discussion from the conclusion. As I said, it is permitted in the first place as חפצא, but "gets forbidden" because of Midos, i.g. גברא. Did you understand that part? it is like R' ovadia Zl was asking about using condoms in Arayot, so he spent like 10 pages proving it is not Arayot and the conclusion was "there's no way of allowing this". I try my best to show the fine details of every question that many do not see.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, bad Midos such as cruelty do forbid killing, I didn't say  everybody permits, I just showed the fineprinting. We should learn to read the Psakim between the lines.

Comment: There’s reading between the lines, and there’s reading between the lines at the expense of the lines themselves. You want to quote the Noda BiYehudah as saying that hunting is permissible? I have no problem with that. But make sure you quote the part where he qualifies that ruling as well.

Answer (score -1):

It is a sin not to put an animal out of its suffering of pain and keep it alive, **when it has a constructive purpose** in its death e.g shechita for the sake of food.

> Bava Bathra 73b:
>   ואמר רבה בר בר חנה זימנא חדא הוה קא אזלינן במדברא וחזינן הנהו אווזי דשמטי גדפייהו משמנייהו וקא נגדי נחלי דמשחא מתותייהו אמינא להו אית לן בגוייכו חלקא לעלמא דאתי חדא דלי גדפא וחדא דלי אטמא כי אתאי לקמיה דרבי אלעזר אמר לי עתידין ישראל ליתן עליהן את הדין
>   In summary Rabba bar bar Chana went to the desert on his travels and saw the fat geese that were so fat when they lifted their wings oil flowed out. These were destined to be slaughtered for Tzadikim to eat, and Rabbi Elazar said that we will be brought to account on the geeses behalf, for delaying the end of days when they will be eaten.
>
> Rashi:
>   ליתן עליהם את הדין - שבחטאתם מתעכב משיח **ויש להם צער בעלי חיים לאותן אווזים מחמת שומנן:**
>   i.e the delay of Moshiach keeps them alive and causes these geese pain to move because they are so full of fat.
>
> Shitta mekubetzet:עתידין ישראל ליתן עליהם את הדין. פירוש **כשאוכלים אותם לעתיד לבוא מנכים להם מזכיותיהן**
>   i.e we will lose our merits for the anguish we caused those geese to stay alive when Moshiach comes and we finally slaughter and eat the geese at the feast.

Comment: I don’t see where you’re getting your inference from. Since these geese were intended for the times of Mashiach, they couldn’t be shechted before then, and so even Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim isn’t enough to spare them? Maybe that case is different, since they’re designated for the times of Mashiach (or since the geese signaled to him that they were intended as such); therefore we can’t kill them except for that purpose. Perhaps by an ordinary animal that’s suffering one might be obligated to kill it.

Comment: (Con’t) Let me put it this way: if these animals are in such pain, to the point that we are punished every day for prolonging their suffering, would the one who ends their pain not be praiseworthy? We simply are not able to do so until Mashiach comes. For any other animal, which does not have that restriction, shouldn’t we save them immediately?

Comment: @DonielF when we do aveiros we don't even realise we are causing animals harm, if we are punished for causing animals harm when we not thinking , how much more so we should be punished for actively seeing animals suffering which can be used to feed ourselves and end their misery before they suffer more.

Comment: Again, maybe that animal is different since it’s specifically designated for the times of Mashiach, but for ones which aren’t, one *should* put them out of their misery.

Comment: @DonielF read my previous comment i meant i am agreeing with you that we should put the animal out of their misery the geese dedicated for mashiach are inaccessible but regular animals if they can be shechted then they should as a constructive purpose to be put them out of their misery

Comment: I don’t see any indication in this Gemara that requires animals in general to be killed for food if they are suffering.

Comment: @Donielf the quicker they get slaughtered for the seuda of moshiach, the less punishment we will incurr see shitta mekubetzes i quoted

Comment: But that’s only because they’re designated for Mashiach. If they aren’t designated for Mashiach, who says that you have to shecht them for food?

Comment: Because otherwise they will suffer and we will be punished just like we are punished for making the geese suffer. **Tzaar baalei chaim(quoted in Rashi) is an issur on all animals**@DonielF

Comment: You’re not telling me anything that wasn’t presumed in the OP. I know Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim is assur on all animals, that’s why I’m asking whether one may/must put it out of its misery. You still haven’t demonstrated that one may not kill it unless it’s for a constructive purpose.

Comment: @doniel you said "I know Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim is assur on all animals" and yet when Rashi says that  not shechting the Moshiach seuda geese is Tzaar baalei chaim, you say "But that’s only because they’re designated for Mashiach," either Tzaar baalei chaim applies to other animals fit for consumption as well (when not shechting them), or it doesn't apply at all in which case why did Rabbi Elazar say we will be punished? unless you want to argue with rashi that its not because of tzaar baale chaim.

Comment: I’m clearly not getting this across very well, so let’s start over. Rashbam says that we’re going to be punished for the Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim of these geese, right? So if someone could *prevent* that Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim, that should be a good thing, right? In this particular case, that’s impossible, since the geese are designated for Mashiach, but in a different case, where Mashiach isn’t a factor, that should be permissible.

Comment: @donielf yes.... but not permissible rather mandatory, and  if the suffering animal is not shechted when it has use for food this is sinful.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I’m not seeing how you’re proving that definitively from these texts.