# Animal in excruciating pain on Shabbos: What lenient opinions exist?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, animals, slaughter-shochet-shecht, suffering

Are there *any* respected poskim who would permit killing (with a shinui) a bug or other small creature who is clearly suffering *terribly* on Shabbos?

If not Shabbos, what about Yom Tov?

If not killing, is there anything else you could do?

*Please don't judge me for this question. I understand the answer would seem to be "no," but I also have faith in the power of creative poskim to find a part of the Torah on which good and sensitive instincts may stand.*

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95468/16706

Comment: According to some opinions in the Talmud ([Shab. 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.12a.9?with=all&lang=bi)) it is permitted to kill small insects [on Shabbat, according to Rashi] even when they're not suffering, so there's definitely room to argue that OP's case would likewise be permitted. (See also R. Emden's resp. [§110](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1408&pgnum=117))

Comment: @Oliver Thanks. Do you think it could include cases where the insect in question does reproduce sexually and is not in a position to cause you any harm?

Comment: @SAH In that case what is the given purpose for killing it?

Comment: @Oliver To end its suffering.

Comment: If it really, really troubles you, a non-Jew may be asked to heal or care for the suffering animal.

Comment: @Oliver There are certain prerequisites to killing such insects on shabbat; like danger or tza'ar. Otherwise, all insects(except for lice) are forbidden to kill on a Rabbinic level.

Comment: Same with yom tov. And why kill it? Maybe it could be saved!

Comment: @SAH In that case, IMHO, R. Emden -for one- would permit it.

Comment: @chachamNisan Please see the Yave"tz I referenced.

Comment: @Oliver I wish I could read this source. Are you able to summarize R'Emden's opinion, and perhaps post it as an answer? If he indeed says this, it's an amazing find. If others agree, even better.

Comment: @Oliver The responsa is a good find! He states that tza'ar ba'alei chaim doesn't apply to insects(rather only to animals that "work", dogs and cats) and that it is permitted to kill insects that cause tza'ar or present danger. It didn't mention anything about killing insects for no reason on shabbat or killing a suffering animal on shabbat. I'm pretty sure the Ya'avetz ztz"l holds it's assur mi'd'oraita to kill mammals on shabbat(unless they present a danger, like the Talmud rules).

Comment: @SAH Mammals are forbidden to kill(or even cause bleeding) on a Torah-level; while insects are forbidden on a Rabbinic level.

Comment: @chachamNisan To be accurate, he says "maybe it applies to dogs and cats too (because they're domesticated and humans can sustain from them a profitable relationship). His quote of Rav Nachman (left column, first line) is with regards to Shabbat. Furthermore, his premise follows -as he says so explicitly- that there wouldn't be any prohibition of "*netilat neshamah*" by insects [which tza'ar b"c does not pertain to].